# How can i fix Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String`

Tags: c#, winforms

I get trying to get data using the following code

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String`

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.IsGetData)
            {
                DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row).Row as DataRow;

                string value = (string)row["BOM - RIM PN"]; 
                var results = from myRow in this.wHLMASTERDETAIL.RIMS.AsEnumerable()
                              where myRow.Field<string>("STOCK NO") == value
                              select myRow;
                e.Value = results.ToList().Count;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
string value = row["BOM - RIM PN"].ToString();
```

In case you need some extra work for null values(maybe skip them) you need additional type check.

Comment: Although this does the job, the reason is the type special case with DBNull, the user of this sort of code must be aware of why this exactly works. Casting to string must not be done via .ToString at almost all circumstances. +1 for the working answer, and the explanation to state for additional type check.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's `DBNull` firstly and return an empty string or whatever is appropriate in your case. Otherwise call `ToString()` on it.

```
var boxRim = row["BOM - RIM PN"];
string value  = (bomRim == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : bomRim.ToString();
```